# Concatenating CSV Files using Pandas is causing Duplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I was writing a python method on Google Colab in order to go into a folder of 84 .csv's, concatenate them and output a new .csv

Here is the method

```
def concatenate(indirectory = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Folder/Folder", outfile = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/--.csv"):
  os.chdir(indirectory)
  fileList = glob.glob("*.csv")
  dfList = []
  colnames = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
  for filename in fileList:
      print(filename)
      df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)
      dfList.append(df)
  concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis = 0)
  concatDf.columns = colnames
  concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index = None)
```

This worked as far as concatenating the files to an extent, the headers were duplicated into new rows, which I manually removed but it would be nice to know how to remove them within the method.

However, this took some of the IDs held in Column A, and duplicated them across rows where Column A was empty. I didn't realise until I started to perform some analysis on the data involving column A and

```
aCount = df['A'].value_counts()
```

was showing some of the IDs being duplicated into empty rows a large number of times.

Comment: Can you give more specifics about your problem?

Comment: @swhat I want to concatenate the 84 csv files, they all share an identical format and have the same headers. I want the output file to only have the headers once at the top (but I can manually delete those rows if need be) the issue is that IDs from column A are repeating themselves into rows where A has no data available.

Comment: Sure, like you said, but what is the expected shape vs the real shape

Comment: I want the final csv to have the 12 columns and all other data going down vertically, it is currently doing that, just with the headers being duplicated and issues with the ID in column A showing up duplicated in places that should not contain any data

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you mean by the "ID in column A showing up duplicated"

Comment: So the 84 csv files relate to crimes reported by a police force, column A is Crime IDs, not all rows had a Crime ID but this method is giving a Crime ID from other columns and filling it in to rows where it should be blank - although some rows are still staying blank so I don't understand the cause.

Comment: It might be helpful if you can provide a few of the sample csv in snippets to help reproduce the problem.  Make sure the snippets actually reproduce the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be having a problem with your column index. The header duplication is caused because you are telling pandas that your csvs have no headers, so it is reading the first row of the csv as data, but it sounds like the headers are really there so they are being included in the dataframes as data instead. It's possible that this is also messing with your index, which could cause the duplicated data.

```
for filename in fileList:
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename) # if the headers are the same, use them (i.e. don't use header=None if the headers are present)
    # df.columns = colnames # if they are not the same, you should make them the same
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0) # you can also add arg ignore_index=True to concat on column order rather than column name
concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=False)
```

Comment: When I was trying to work out the issue, I removed the colnames variable and the concatDf.columns = colnames and instead tried to make 

    header = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]

But this threw an error saying it wanted an integer value

Comment: the header arg in `read_csv` is expecting the 0-indexed row number of headers to read, not the actual column names. You can set the column names after reading it.

Comment: How can I set that correctly then to handle 12 existing headed columns?

Comment: You can omit the header argument if you want to use the header in your dataframe and it is the first row of the file. Omission is equivalent to setting `header=0`. If the headers are the same across all files, then this will be enough to allow you to concatenate them correctly. If they are different, then you can set df.columns after reading the csv.